# bundle update seems to be deleting my .gem file

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I am new to building gems, so bear with me.

**Scenario:**

```
[Gemfile]
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'curriculous', path: '/mydev/curriculous'
```

---

```
$ ls /mydev/curriculous
Gemfile             Rakefile            curriculous.sublime-project
Gemfile.lock            bin             curriculous.sublime-workspace
LICENSE.txt         curriculous-0.0.1.alpha.gem lib
README.md           curriculous.gemspec     spec
```

---

```
$ bundle update
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using curriculous (0.0.1.alpha) from source at /mydev/curriculous
Using bundler (1.3.5)
Your bundle is updated!
```

---

```
$ ls /mydev/curriculous
Gemfile             Rakefile            curriculous.sublime-workspace
Gemfile.lock            bin             lib
LICENSE.txt         curriculous.gemspec     spec
README.md           curriculous.sublime-project
```

---

**Question:**
where did my .gem file go? What am I doing wrong?

#### Addendum 1

- The gemfile above is in my testfile. I've uploaded it to github:
  https://github.com/pitosalas/testcur
- The gem itself is also now on github:
  https://github.com/pitosalas/curriculous
- The version of gem (gem -v) is  2.0.2
- I admit again that I've not done this before so I probably have something totally boneheaded that I am doing.
- I think I am trying to do something a little tricky and there might be a much better way to do it too
- But this weird behavior of the .gem file being deleted doesn't fit any of my mental models of gems and so on that I would like to track down what is going on.

Comment: Why does this `.gem` file live at the top of the path and not in a subdirectory like `pkg`, as is typical?

Comment: I don't know, that's where gem build puts it. Is that unusual?

Comment: @pitosalas Are you implying that `bundle update` is deleting the gem file you built?

Comment: yes, it is happening in front of my eyes. See the listings above!

Comment: @pitosalas This question belongs to wizardry.stackechange.com

Comment: hmm...not a very useful comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `Gemfile` that you're showing the one inside `curriculous` itself, or a second project that uses `curriculous`?

If it's the one inside `curriculous`, then you should remove the `gem 'curriculous', path: '/mydev/curriculous'` line. That indicates that curriculous depends on itself, which is probably not what you mean :)

Instead, add a line that has only `gemspec`. This tells Bundler to read the `curriculous.gemspec` file to find the dependencies for the project.

There's a basic tutorial for creating gems at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ruby/gem-creation-with-bundler/

If that `Gemfile` is for a different project, then you're doing it correctly. Is there something that isn't working?  Running `bundle` will rebuild the gem. The specifics of what it does depends on what version of RubyGems is active. Can you post `gem --version`?

Comment: See addenda to op above

Comment: Is there something not working other than the file vanishing? As André mentioned on the Bundler mailing list, when you use `path` it doesn't actually need a `gem` file because it just uses the files in the given path directly.

Comment: Honestly I don't think I understand it in depth enough to say if everything else is working as expected. In any event I didn't get it to work and this was just one oddity that I couldn't explain. But I did see what André said and have read more about that topic. Here's a great link about that and related topics: http://yehudakatz.com/2010/12/16/clarifying-the-roles-of-the-gemspec-and-gemfile/

In any event, for me this is not a blocker anymore because I've changed approaches. It is still a matter of intellectual curiosity but for now I am closing this.